# Why uses TYPO3 smallint(5) instead of tinyint(1) for storing BOOLEAN values in database?

Tags: boolean, extbase, typo3-8.x

In TYPO3 8.7.x the datatype for booleans in MySQL-Database are `smallint(5)` and I wonder why it is not `tinyint(1)`. In example for fields like "deleted" and "hidden". So, is there a good reason not to use `tinyint(1)` for storing boolean values in my own extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same question. It seems `tinyint` is MySQL specific. Doctrine dbal maps that to `smallint` to be db agnostic. (Learned on Slack, thanks to Christian Kuhn!)

`smallint` is a signed integer, while `tinyint` is unsigned, according to [Doctrine's documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/types.html#smallint):

> Not all of the database vendors support unsigned integers, so such an assumption might not be propagated to the database.